# help understanding stash context=""

Tags: stash

I'm not able to make sense of how to use context="" in stash.

I've not yet had to use it but I'm not sure if there are things I may have been able to handle more efficiently.

could somebody give an example please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Think of `context` as a prefix to the `name` parameter (that is in fact exactly how it works in the background). This enables you to use dynamic variables (or 'variable variables') that have the same `name` but might be used in different contexts. You don't have to use `context` - you could achieve the same thing with a dynamic name parameter e.g.: `name="faqs-related-to-{entry_id}"`

Personally, every site I build has a dedicated and permanent development/staging environment in addition to the live/production environment (and local environments per developer). So for me, `context` is an ideal way of scoping my Stash variables to the environment so that, for example, cached Stash lists are unique per environment. Without using `context` I'd have private draft status entries appearing on the live site due to the caching.

Here's an example of a cached list of 'news' entries where the staging environment's list can be different to the production environment's list thanks to `context`. Notice too that on the inside of the `channel:entries` loop I have another Stash list for the categories, which, instead of using `context`, achieves the same thing with the `name` parameter. (I prefer this as I always reserve the `context` parameter for environment scoping):

```
{exp:stash:set_list
    name="news-items"
    parse="yes"
    parse_depth="2"
    context="{global:env}"
    save="yes"
    replace="{global:stash_cache_replace}"
    scope="site"
    bundle="news"
}
    {exp:channel:entries
        channel="news"
        disable="member_data|pagination"
        dynamic="no"
        status="{global:entry_statuses}"
    }
        {stash:item-id}{entry_id}{/stash:item-id}
        {stash:item-title}{title}{/stash:item-title}
        {stash:item-date}{entry_date}{/stash:item-date}
        {stash:item-url}{if page_url}{page_url}{if:else}{url_title_path=news}{/if}{/stash:item-url}
        {stash:item-thumb}{news_img}{/stash:item-thumb}

        {exp:stash:set_list:2 name="cats-of-{entry_id}" context="{global:env}"}
            {categories}
                {stash:cat}{category_name}{/stash:cat}
                {stash:cat-url}{path=news}{/stash:cat-url}
            {/categories}
        {/exp:stash:set_list:2}

    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}
```

(`{global:env}` is set in my config bootstrap and equates to "live" or "dev" depending on the environment, while `{global:entry_statuses}` equates to "open" or "open|draft" depending on the environment).